# sbt assembly is giving error

Tags: scala, apache-spark, sbt

> C:\scala\spark-1.6.1-bin-hadoop2.6\spark-1.6.1-bin-hadoop2.6>sbt assembly
>
> Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=256m; su
>   port was removed in 8.0
>
> [info] Set current project to spark-1-6-1-bin-hadoop2-6 (in build file:/C:/scal
>   /spark-1.6.1-bin-hadoop2.6/spark-1.6.1-bin-hadoop2.6/)
>
> [error] Not a valid command: assembly
>
> [error] Not a valid project ID: assembly
>
> [error] Expected ':' (if selecting a configuration)
>
> [error] Not a valid key: assembly
>
> [error] assembly
>
> [error]         ^

Tried everything given on web,still unable to sort out this issue,any help/pointers please ...

["./sbt/sbt assembly" errors "Not a valid command: assembly" for Apache Spark project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21245669/sbt-sbt-assembly-errors-not-a-valid-command-assembly-for-apache-spark-pro)

above solution is also not working...

Comment: Have you added sbt-assembly to the plugins.sbt file?

Comment: is this step needed on windows?if yes,please guide me,i hadnt done

Comment: Directory name "spark-1.6.1-bin-hadoop2.6" looks like you have binary distribution of Spark. So possibly you just don't have sbt project file(s) in this directory (check build.sbt)

Comment: yes,i dont have sbt folder here..i cant see build.sbt

Comment: What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: I am just trying to run a simple wordCount program on spark/scala using intellij editor.since sbt assembly is failing,I am getting below exception in intellij console   Error:scalac: Error: org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.remote.ServerException
Error compiling sbt component 'compiler-interface-2.10.1-52.0'          

found somewhere on net that issue is related to error of sbt assembly

Comment: wats wrong in sbt assembly command here...any pointers to solve this..

Comment: You probably need to run `sbt package` instead if you are trying to compile your scala program?

Answer (score 1):

Problem is you have not added `sbt-assembly` plugin.

In windows, `C:\Users\<username>\.sbt\0.13\plugins\plugins.sbt` and add

```
addSbtPlugin("com.eed3si9n" % "sbt-assembly" % "0.11.2")
```

then it will work. Explained [here](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-assembly)

Comment: in "C:\Users\<username>\.sbt\0.13"  dont have plugins folder,so i created myself and compiled,but still have same error.

Comment: @Anand add the file to your **project** directory located at the root of your project.